# How to prevent table from resizing?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I feel like I've tried everything. `table-layout: fixed` didn't work, `vertical-align:top` didn't work too, `overflow: hidden`...
No matter what I do, I can't prevent the table from resizing when I go to `<EditItemTemplate>` on my page.
my code:

**HTML & CSS:**

```css
.main_table{
            height: 100%;
            width: 80%;
            background-color: transparent;
            /*border: 1px solid white;*/
            /*min-height: 61vh;*/
            padding: 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .album{
            width: 7.5vw;
            height: 7.5vw;
            border: 3px solid lightgray;
            margin-top: -10px;
        }
        .inside{
            width: 31.35vh;
            /*width:100%;*/
              height:30.4vh;
              max-height:30.4vh;
              max-width: 31.35vh;
              border:5px solid #fff;
              background:
                radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left    ,transparent 97%,#fff) bottom right,
                radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right   ,transparent 97%,#fff) bottom left,
                radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,transparent 97%,#fff) top right,
                radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 97%,#fff) top left;
              background-size:30px 30px; /* adjust this */
              background-repeat:no-repeat;
              position: relative;
        }
        .border{
            /*border: 5px solid white;*/
        }
        #continuation{
            min-height: 39vh;
            background-color: white;
            width: 80%;
        }
        .behind{
            height: 61.4%;
            width: 79.85%;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 1px solid white;
            min-height: 61vh;
            z-index: -1;
            position: absolute;
            top: -2px;
            right: 10.07vw;
            /*max-height: 61vh;*/
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .squares{
            height: 28.2vh;
            width: 29.2vh;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        .special{
            /*border: 0px;
            padding-top: 4px;*/
        }
        .special2{
            border: 4px solid white;
        }
        .album_button{
            background-color: transparent;
              border: 3px solid #8B8B8B;
              color: #8B8B8B;
              padding: 6px 15px;
              text-align: center;
              display: inline-block;
              cursor: pointer;
              border-radius: 30px;
              outline: 0;
        }
        button > .img,
        button > span {
          vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .album_button:hover{
            border: 3px solid lightgray;
            color: lightgray;
        }
        .ID{
            font-size: 10px;
            color: gray;
            top: 0;
        }
        .above_ID{
            text-align: right;
            padding-right: 30px;
            padding-top: 2px;
        }
        .above_c{
            text-align:center;
             /*overflow: hidden;*/ 
        }
        .above_c_special{
            text-align:center;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<center>
      <asp:DataList ID="dtlproducts" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dtlproducts_SelectedIndexChanged" OnCancelCommand="dtlproducts_CancelCommand" OnUpdateCommand="dtlproducts_UpdateCommand">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <table id="Table1" runat="server" CellPadding="0" cellspacing="0" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="Center" Class="main_table">
       <tr Class="border">
            <td Class="border">
                <center>
                    <table class="inside">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="above_ID"><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Id:" CssClass="ID"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Vinyl_ID") %>' CssClass="ID"></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="above_c"><center><asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" CssClass="album" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Vinyl_Image","pics/{0}") %>'></asp:Image></center></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="above_c"><asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblpname" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Vinyl_Name") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="above_c"><asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Price:"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblprice" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Vinyl_Price") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="above_c"><asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Quantity:"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblqua" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Vinyl_Quantity") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="above_c_special"><asp:Button ID="btnorder" runat="server" Text="ADD" CommandName="select" CssClass="album_button"><%--<div class="img"></div>--%><%--<span>ADD</span>--%></asp:Button></td>
                          </tr>
                      </table>
                    </center>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
            </table>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
         <table id="Table1" runat="server" CellPadding="0" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="main_table">
            <tr Class="border">
              <td Class="border">
                <center>
                  <table class="inside">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="above_ID"><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Id:" CssClass="ID"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Vinyl_ID") %>' CssClass="ID"></asp:Label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="above_c"><center><asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" CssClass="album" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Vinyl_Image","pics/{0}") %>'></asp:Image></center></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="above_c"><asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblpname" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Vinyl_Name") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="above_c"><asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Price:"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblprice" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Vinyl_Price") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="above_c"><asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Quantity:"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblqua" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Vinyl_Quantity") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="above_c_special"><asp:Button ID="btnconfirm" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="CONFIRM" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button>
                          <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="CANCEL" CommandName="cancel" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button>
                           <asp:DropDownList ID="drpqua" runat="server" CssClass="album_button">
                               <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                </tr>
             </table>
           </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:datalist>
```

*The page when I'm on `<ItemTemplate>` (good and working, everything's in place):*
[image]

*The page when I'm on `<EditItemTemplate>` (the border resizes, which makes everything move a little):*
[image]

Comment: Have you tried fixed width: width: <something here>

Comment: @SoJs I've tried limiting the max-width of `.inside` which didn't work as well

Comment: It looks to me like there are different styles being applied to it. Inspect and compare the styles for both instances and adjust accordingly. Generally speaking though, the sure way to prevent unwanted resizing is to set the table as well as the cells to a fixed width.

Comment: @JuanR I used the same style for both `<EditItemTemplate>` and `<ItemTemplate>`, the same classes are associated with all of the tags in both... set the cells to a fixed width, do you mean just by setting the `width: ...px`, `height: ...px`, or is there anything else? (like `potision`, or `max-width`)

Comment: There might be some styles being applied without you realizing it. Do what I suggested and compare the styles. The gray border that shows on edit mode is indicative of this.

Comment: @JuanR gray border? there's only a white 4px border that exists in both styles to hide areas where the background is shown. I compared the styles, they're the same... I think I need to add something to the table to keep it from moving, I'll try those fixed cells but I need to know if it's just `height` and `width` or other things as well.

Comment: @kfirezer my good friend, open the DEV tools in your browser, select the element that is changing when you edit and look at the **Computed** tab. Compare the values of the styles to the other state. You should be able to see what changed and what CSS class is causing the change.